Is there a "High Multiplication" operation in Rust?
Throughout, I will say u16 and u32 many times. This should be understood to be a standin for uX, and u2X for any integer X (e.g. u8 and u16, u16 and u32, u32 and u64, u64 and u128).
If x, y are integers (say u16s), their product x*y is naturally a u32 z, which can be written as z = z0 + (z1 << 16). If one only wants to compute z0, this can be done easily with u16::wrapping_mul. Is there such a command if you only want to compute z1? I particiularly want the high_mul command to have type fn high_mul(x: u16, y: u16) -> u16. It is of course very easy to write such a command yourself --- I'm mostly interested in a command that the Rust complier will lower to the appropriate mulhi command that exists on certain embedded devices (I don't have a particular target in mind, but I've heard this is a very common instruction).
I would also be interested in a way to compute such a command using a small number of wrapping u16 muls. Achieving 3 appears to be simple using a variant of Karatsuba multiplication (which requires certain additional additions and masking, which I'm fine with), so I'm mostly interested in an implementation that uses 2 u16::wrapping_muls or (ideally) 1.

Inline assembly is always a worst-case option.

@ChayimFriedman yes, and it would be a good option if I had a particular target in mind. I'm mostly wondering if someone has gone through the effort of writing such a high_mul function that maps to the correct inline assembly for several common embedded targets.

Llvm doesn't have an ir level instruction for this, so there's no real way to lower it in a platform geberic manner that offers any benefit over (x * y)>>n. You just kind of need to hope the instruction selector can recognise that. Do you have an example of bad code being generated?

@user1937198 I think that answers my question in the negative then, namely there's no reliable way to do this without specifying a platform, at which point you might as well use inline assembly.

The way its supposed to work in LLVM is that you write (x * y)>>n and then the instruction selection dag combiner detects that pattern and lowers it to an LLVM instruction selection dag node for a mulhu. At which point the target can then lower the mulhu appropriatly. The relevant code is at https://llvm.org/doxygen/DAGCombiner_8cpp.html#ab5a426cb5c2105ca954c4ab9f12ef76f

A near solution is available on nightly via u16::widening_mul which returns a (u16, u16) tuple of the low and high bits. If you need stable, the current implementation just promotes to the next highest integer type and splits into high and low halves after the multiply.
You should compile and see for yourself if doing the same thing and discarding the low bits optimizes to a mulhi on your target system.
